# I'm getting an error message regarding datetime

Tags: python, spyder

I'm trying to turn a date with hours into just a date.

Please help me, this is driving me insane.

This is my script:

```
from datetime import datetime
Date1= '2018-2-12 10:30:01'
d = datetime.strptime('Date1','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
day_string = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

and this is the error message:

```
ValueError: time data 'Date1' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: You're trying to parse `'Date1'`
, the string in itself... Use `d = datetime.strptime(Date1,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the variable `Date1` instead of the string `'Date1'`

```
from datetime import datetime
Date1= '2018-2-12 10:30:01'
d = datetime.strptime(Date1,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
day_string = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(day_string)
#2018-02-12
```